# Как использовать сохранённый токен в get запросе

Tags: java, android, api, token

Товарищи подскажите, при авторизации пользователя ему присваивается токен на сервере, я получаю его и сохраняю в файле SharedPreferences:

```
    public void saveToken(String token){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString("token", token);

    editor.apply();
}

public Data getToken(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return new Data(
            sharedPreferences.getString("token", null)
    );
}
```

После этого вызываю этот метод в LoginActivity для сохранения:

```
Call<Data> call = RetrofitClient
            .getInstance().getApi().userLogin(login,pass);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<Data> response) {
            Data Data = response.body();
            if(!Data.isStatus()){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Пора покормить кота!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();}
            else {
                SharedPrefManager.getInstance(LoginActivity.this)
                        .saveUser(Data.getData());

                SharedPrefManager.getInstance(LoginActivity.this)
                        .saveToken(Data.getToken());


                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ChatListActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Data> call, Throwable t) {

        }

    });
```

И вот после этого надо как то передать сохраненный токен в get запрос, чтоб получить список пользователей. Подскажите, как это должно выглядеть в файле с api и надо ли где то ещё что то дописывать?

Comment: у вас же есть метод для получения токена, так же у вас должен быть адрес куда вам нужно обращаться для получения списка пользователей, у вас есть данный адрес?

Comment: {{host}}/users?token={{token}} , это из постмена, host есть, если я  вместо {{token}} вставляю токен из постмена, то всё работает,  вот только вместо  {{token}} надо вставить тот что я сохранил

Comment: получить токен из хранилища можно так как у вас уже написано в коде:
`SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String token = sharedPreferences.getString("token", null)`
и дальше уже вставляйте тот токен что вы сохранили

Comment: то сеть в файл api  я до запроса пишу SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); String token = sharedPreferences.getString("token", null)  , а потом в запросе как вызвать сохраненный токен?

Comment: да, именно так и нужно, при помощи чего вы посылаете запрос? у вас в файле api уже прописан запрос?

Comment: Вот такой: @GET("users?token={{token}}")
    Call<UsersResponse>getData(
    );

Comment: а этот код надо как то в метод писать, или просто так ? получить токен из хранилища можно так как у вас уже написано в коде: SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); String token = sharedPreferences.getString("token", null)

Comment: зачем здесь `{{token}}` две скобки? вы сделали уже один запрос, он у вас судя по всему получился, раз вы сохраняете токен, теперь сделайте такой же и второй запрос, только вместо token передавайте переменную string из предыдущего комментария, будет что-то типа такого `Call<Data> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getData()` но вы не передадите токена так, вам нужно в файле апи в запрос добавить такое: `Call<UsersResponse>getData( @Path("token") token: String)` и тогда при вызове данного метода из активности вам нужно будет записать getData(token)

Comment: "зачем здесь {{token}} две скобки?" - это я скопировал из потмена, и если я заменяю {{token}} на токен, который отображается в постмене, то список контактов получается

Comment: то есть я после : @GET("users?token={{token}}") Call<UsersResponse>getData( ); пишу : Call<UsersResponse>getData( @Path("token") token: String), и я не совсем понял о куда мне записиать это: "и тогда при вызове данного метода из активности вам нужно будет записать  getData(token) "

Comment: у вас отдельный файл апи или вы пишете все вместе в одном классе? делайте все по аналогии с логином

Comment: отдельный файл ( интерфейс если не ошибаюсь)

Comment: просто логин я посылал запросом POST

Comment: этот запрос делайте так как вам нужно, поменяйте метод запроса и все сделайте согласно примеру с логином

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, буду пробовать сделать, пока не совсем понял, но по ходу надеюсь разберусь )